# Submit form doesnt work on the website

Tags: form-submit

First of all thank you for answering. I really , really have no clue what happened to my website form. 
We work on computer repairs not in programming so I'm extremely confused why this doesnt work.
                                            The coding can be found at www.thewrightcorner.com/contactus.html.

I dont see why when I paste it here I cannot see it.

I dont understand any of it,so please help!

```
<form action="contact.php" method="get" style="margin:0; padding:0 "> 
  <div class="w" style=" margin:3 0 0 17px; line-height:12px ">
    Your full name:<input type="text" class="blue" style=" width:222; height:22px; background-color:#41BCEA" name="your_name" /> 
    <br />
    <br style="line-height:7px " />
    E-mail address:<br /><input type="text" class="blue" style=" width:222; height:22px; background-color:#41BCEA" name="your_email" /> 
    <br />
    <br style="line-height:7px " />
    Your telephone:<br /><input type="text" class="blue" style=" width:222px; height:22px; background-color:#41BCEA" name="your_phone" />
  </div>
</form>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="277" height="181">                  
 <div class="w" style=" margin:0 0 0 0px; line-height:12px ">
    Your message:<br />
    <br style="line-height:1px " />
    <textarea name="message" cols="35" rows="35" style=" width:222px; height:112px; overflow:hidden " class="w"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left:98px; margin-top:5px;">
  <input type="image" src="images/6_k1.gif" style=" border-style:none  " />
  <input type="image" style="margin-left:5px; border-style:none " src="images/6_k2.gif" onclick="submit();" />
```

I do have a contact.php file in my root.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here to even begin to help.

Comment: If you paste the form here, then highlight the contents of the form, and click the "Code" format button {} we'll be able to see the code.  Be sure there's nothing sensitive there like connection strings, usernames, passwords, etc before posting it here unless you want to give us all teh keys to the kingdom.

Comment: I tried to copy. Thanks for the advice, in this point my password would do no good to anybody. Frustration set in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button is outside of your form. Move it inside the `form` tags. So is your Message field actually.

These elements should all be within the same `form` tag.